# Convert from hexadecimal to Unicode in R language

Tags: r

I want to create Unicode from consecutive hexadecimal numbers in R language.

For example `\u005C` can be converted to characters, `paste0 ("\u", "005C")` cannot be converted to characters.

Therefore, the following function cannot be created.

```
hex.chr <- function(hex){paste0("\u", hex)}
hex.chr("005C")
```

In the above case, how can I create a function that converts to Unicode just by entering `005C`, for example?

Comment: Maybe `intToUtf8(0x005C)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `intToUtf8` and `paste` `0x` to be recognised as *hex*.

```
hex.chr <- function(hex) {intToUtf8(paste0("0x", hex))}
hex.chr("005C")
#[1] "\\"
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
x <- "\u005C"
y <- "005C"

eq_char_from_s <- function(s){
  rawToChar(as.raw(strtoi(y, 16L)))
}

z <- eq_char_from_s(y)

x == z
#> [1] TRUE
print(z)
#> [1] "\\"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>